# Plugin development, js scripts added above of standard jquery...?

Tags: jquery

I develop a joomla system plugin and add some scripts by this way:

```
public function __construct(&$subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $doc->addScript( JURI::base() . 'plugins/system/thebestcheck/js/thebestscripts.js' );

}
```

This works, but my js file is loaded above of jQuery standard file, how can I move it below if standard jquery?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a plugin event that loads the JS file after the `head` has been loaded

Comment: Which event is it? I tested more events but always the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework') or JHtml::('jQuery.framework') above the line addScript line.

Whenever we are creating custom extensions then we must include dependencies.By using this, it will automatically set proper ordering as you want. For more details kindly refer the following link:
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

Best Regards,
Ruchika

Answer (score 0):

call JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); before your $doc = ... line

Comment: although this line of code may solve the problem, it's good to include some explanations.